# Share my localhost over router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, localhost

### The problem:

I want to share my localhost, which is currently set up to `http://sohan.com` by `hosts` file in `system32\drivers\etc` folder. I want to access it directly from any other devices that can access my router either by WiFi or cable.

I have read so many answers here and other sites but nothing did work. Because my setup is much different than other.

### My current configuration:

Windows 7 Service Pack 1 64bit

TP-Link WR740N

Local Server using EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11

### My Setup:

I have one Desktop and one Laptop and some mobile devices that are connected to the router.

The Desktop is special here. Because I use a 3G dial-up modem on my desktop and share that internet to the router. Now every device have access to the same internet.

The Desktop is connected to the WAN(Blue colored) port of the router by a cable. Which supposed to be a Broadband access. Now my Desktop is the Broadband provider. I want to share the desktop's localhost along the internet so that I can access that from any devices I want.

It should be noted that I cannot access the desktop from any devices in this setup, only internet is shared. I cannot access files or don't get response if I ping with my desktop's ip from any devices.

Now I want a solution for this. I need both internet and localhost to be shared from my desktop.

Comment: This requires you port forward all traffic on the given port to the machine.  Have you done that?

Comment: I'm actually not so familiar with networking like this, so a little bit unsure. Do I have to do port forwarding in my router?

Comment: Only place you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

By accessing your localhost, I'm guessing you mean you want them to access your computer. Are you able to access it by IP now? If so, then most of the hard work is done and all you're looking for is a name lookup server, or a local DNS.

I've been able to accomplish this by using dnsmasq on my router. That way, I can simply edit my router's /etc/hosts file to do internal DNS. To use dnsmasq, I installed OpenWRT on my router. I'm sure there's a simpler way to install dnsmasq, but i'm not aware of it.

Comment: If you are going to talk about editing the router using OpenWRT, host file, then you should explain specifically how to do it.  Most people in this situation would not know how to do it.